# Пропадает коллекция(List<>) при передачи в RedirectToAction() asp.net core (MVC)

Tags: asp.net-core, коллекции, redirect

Не получается передать коллекцию в индекс, она попросту пропадает не известно где. Тоже самое случается если попробовать передать класс User с полем iCollection, все другие поля(инт, стринг) передаются хорошо, но коллекция опять пуста. В общем, как передать туда полностью класс? В чем причина то?

Экшен который делает Редирект

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string Login, string Password)
    {

        //var a = db.Users.Include(p => p.MyElem).Where;
        //string Query = $"SELECT [Id], [Login], [Password] FROM [Papka(praktika)].[dbo].[Users] where Login='{Login}' and Password='{Password}'";
        //System.Linq.IQueryable<User> a = db.Users.FromSql(Query);
        System.Linq.IQueryable<User> a = db.Users.Include(p => p.MyElem).Where(p => p.Login == Login && p.Password==Password);
        int g =await a.Include(p => p.MyElem).CountAsync<User>();
        if (g > 0)
        {
            User t =await a.FirstAsync<User>();
            List<OneElem> r = t.MyElem.ToList();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Ocenk", r);
        }else
            return View();

    }
```

Экшен который принимает по Редиректу

```
public class OcenkController : Controller
{
    public IActionResult Index(List<OneElem> log)
    {
        return View(log);
    }
}
```

Модель Юзер

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ICollection<OneElem> MyElem { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Не указан login")]
    [MinLength(2)] 
    [MaxLength(20)]
    public string Login { get; set; }

    [Remote(action: "Vhod", controller: "Home", ErrorMessage = "Неправильный пароль. Длина пароля должна больше 3 символов.")]
    public string Password { get; set; }


    public User()
    {
        MyElem = new List<OneElem>();
    }
```

до передача класса
[image: до передача класса]
После передачи класса

[image: После передачи класса]
До передачи коллекции в Редирект(имеется два элемента)
[image: До передачи коллекции в Редирект(имеется два элемента)]
После приема
[image: После приема]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем причину выяснил, нельзя передавать сложные объекты. Так что решением в данном случае была передача массива.

Answer (score 0):

```
return RedirectToAction("Index", "Ocenk", new { log = r });
```

Comment: Ничего не случилось, как было так и осталось